# TableView. Observing changes: observing of non-property data

Tags: javafx, observable

I use JavaFX to create interface for my program. So I have `TableView` that represent list of such objects

```
public class CQuestAnswer
{   
    private SimpleStringProperty sCaption;
    private CQuestStage stgNext;
}
```

`stgNext` is a pointer to existing object or `null` if there is on acceptable one.

I need to observe changes of list items, so I set listeners when I create `ObservableList`

```
    ObservableList<CQuestAnswer> olData = FXCollections.observableList(lstANswers, (CQuestAnswer param) -> {

        param.paramSCaption().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
            setQuestionnaireChanged(true);
        });

        return new Observable[]{param.paramSCaption()
                                };
    });
```

To observe `stgNext` I need to do the same. But as far as `stgNext` is not `Property` and I need to observe changes of itself not its members value. I mean that when user changes next step `stgNext` pointer changes its value, not object that it points.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you just make `stgNext` into a property?

Comment: It looks like it will break model view architecture. We discussed it with you previuosly and I know that you do not think so :)

In this project I try to avoid observables in data model. Is it possible or not?

Comment: I disagree with that, but as I pointed out in that question, you can still use regular Java Beans in your model and just provide a `JavaBeanPropertyAdapter` for the `TableView` if you want to avoid JavaFX Properties in your model. What is wrong with that approach?

Comment: I used in to write in C++ and now relearn to write code in Java. What more I think, the more I come to believe that you are right.

Comment: Sorry for stupid question but what is better to read to learn how to extend `Property`? I can not find clear example and I think I miss undersatnding of theory. I suppose I'm not the first one

Comment: Why do you want to extend it? Regular use is covered in the [Oracle tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107)